# Updating a cell containing data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to calculate an updating difference between for example A1:A2, and I want to write the result on A3, and automatically update the value of A2 with the result written in A3.
PS: I'm using Google online app for excel I can make it with this?

Comment: Write =A3 in cell A2 .

Comment: Your question is not very clear, can you please edit it to be more clear as to exactly what you are asking. It looks like you want the difference between A1 and A2 to be in A3 and then A2 to update to the value of A3 automatically, this will cause a loop.
Example:
A1 = 10
A2 = 20
A3 would then be 10, but then A2 would update to 10 thus causing A3 to update to 0 and then A2 to -10 then A3 to -10 and so on.